# mypy can't find type hints for black

Tags: python, mypy, python-black

I have a file `test.py` which only contains the line `import black`. When I run `mypy test.py`, I get the following error:

```
test.py:1: error: Skipping analyzing 'black': found module but no type hints or library stubs
test.py:1: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

However, when I look at the [source](https://github.com/psf/black/blob/master/black.py) for `black`, it seems like everything has type hints. **What do I need to do differently in `mypy` to get it to use the type hints when I import `black`?**

Environment setup:

```sh
conda create -n test python=3.7 -y
conda activate test
pip install black mypy
```

EDIT - From [the link mentioned in the error message](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#missing-imports):

> Mypy will not try inferring the types of any 3rd party libraries you have installed unless they either have declared themselves to be PEP 561 compliant stub package or have registered themselves on typeshed

I had assumed `black` have satisfied one of these requirements, but it does not seem to be registered on [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/third_party). From [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installed_packages.html#installed-packages), it seems that a package must have a `py.typed` file to be PEP 561-compliant with inline annotations, and `black` doesn't seem to have that either.

My question still stands - given that the typing information is already there in `black`, how can I (without needing a PR to be approved somewhere) get `mypy` to use that?

I don't see any details about the `py.typed` file - if that is just an empty file and only its existence matters, I assume I can create it somewhere and then typing will work?

Comment: I created an [issue](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1316) on `black`'s GitHub repo to see if they'll add a `py.typed` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - this has been fixed in `black` now ([PR here](https://github.com/psf/black/pull/1395), merged 5/8/2020), so in new versions no workaround is necessary.

---

Creating an empty file named `py.typed` in the install directory is sufficient:

```sh
cd ~/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages # or wherever your packages are installed
# black.py is directly in site-packages, but py.typed needs to be in a directory for the module
mkdir black
touch black/py.typed
```