# Why isn't mypy seeing types from typeshed?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mypy

I'm trying to add more mypy type annotations to my existing codebase. I have a file that uses a lot of bs4.

When I run the mypy checker on this file I get the error:

```
error: Skipping analyzing "bs4": module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker
```

In the [mypy docs on "Missing library stubs"](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-library-stubs-or-py-typed-marker) it says:

> Mypy will not try inferring the types of any 3rd party libraries you have installed unless they either have declared themselves to be PEP 561 compliant stub package (e.g. with a py.typed file) or have registered themselves on **typeshed**, the repository of types for the standard library and some 3rd party libraries.

But when I [look on typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/stubs/beautifulsoup4), there *is* a set of stubs. How do I fix that error and tell it to look at the stub definition from typeshed?

BS4 and mypy are both running the latest version.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60856237/mypy-cant-find-type-hints-for-black) asks a similar question about black, but when I test black in my code mypy doesn't complain but it seems that they've solved it in a different way as there's no black stub in typeshed.

Comment: Does this occur only for bs4, or with other modules in typeshed too?

Comment: @SuperStormer, very wise debug step. I tried it with pillow, and I get: error: Skipping analyzing "PIL": module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the content of [`mypy` typeshed](https://github.com/python/mypy/tree/master/mypy/typeshed). It doesn't include third-party libraries, limited only to standard library. So types for `beautifulsoup` are not shipped with `mypy` (and it would be really odd to do so, because these stubs are updated sometimes more often than `mypy` itself, plus other typecheckers rely on this typeshed). So you need to install required stubs separately ([package home page](https://pypi.org/project/types-beautifulsoup4/)):

```
pip install types-beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any documentation on how to generalise it? Can I assume that if it's in the typeshed repo, I can import it as `types-<folderName>`?

Comment: Yes, it is common convention. Stub packages for package `something` should be called `types-something`. Mentioned [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installed_packages.html#using-installed-packages), so it is official `mypy` position (and other type checkers consider it convenient, so rely on same naming). Note you should never `import` them, only `pip install` (or other installation method) is required. Don't import any types from this packages, it will fail type checking. Import from normal packages, optionally wrapping imports with `if TYPE_CHECKING` and using `annotations` future

Comment: However, [PEP561](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/) enforces `something-stubs` naming (with MUST), so `mypy` was not PEP561-compatible initially. This naming works too (`django-stubs` or [`distutils-stubs`](https://pypi.org/project/docutils-stubs/) exist and are supported by `mypy`).